# yield in staticmethod tied to instance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, static-methods

I wrote this in python 3 and am curious why the generator, produced under the `@staticmethod` decorator by the `yield` statement points to the same generator object per instance, yet produces instance specific results?

```
class Note:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def gen():
        x = 0
        while True:
            x +=1
            yield x

    def id(self):
        print(self.gen)
        a = self.gen
        print(next(a()))


n1 = Note()
n2 = Note()
print(n2.id(),n1.id())
```

This outputs:

```
<function Note.gen at 0x6ffffd7dd08>
1
<function Note.gen at 0x6ffffd7dd08>
1
None None
```

Comment: You create one per instance. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: You are printing the function `self.gen`, not the generator that function returns when called (as `a()`).

Comment: When I saw that they both pointed to the same object 0x6ffffd7dd08 that the state/what point the yield was at would be in that object and would pick up where it left off.

Comment: @staticmethod should almost never be used, especially by beginners.  Move the generator function `gen` outside the class and you will probably be less confused.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not. Try with one instance, the same will happen:

```
n1 = Note()
print(n1.id(), n1.id())
```

It creates one generator per call to `id()`, i.e. per call to `gen()`.

**EDIT (explanation of generators)**

I'll try to explain with this example:

```
>>> def gen():
...  yield 1
...  yield 2
...  yield 3
...  yield 4
...
>>>
>>> gen
<function gen at 0x00000000029119C8>
>>> gen
<function gen at 0x00000000029119C8>
>>> g1 = gen()
>>> g2 = gen()
>>> g1
<generator object gen at 0x00000000025515A0>
>>> g2
<generator object gen at 0x000000000258B870>
>>> next(g1)
1
>>> next(g1)
2
>>> next(g2)
1
>>> next(g2)
2
>>> next(g1)
3
>>>
```

As you can see above, `gen` is not a generator. It is a function. The return value of that function is a generator. So, when I printed `gen` multiple times, I got the same function. However, when I called it twice, I got two generators `g1` and `g2`. Each of them holds its state, as you can see in calls to `next`.

**EDIT 2 (original example fixed)**

BTW, I guess in your code you were trying to do this:

```
import itertools

class Note:
    gen = itertools.count(1)

    def __init__(self):
        self.id = next(self.gen)

n1 = Note()
n2 = Note()
print(n2.id, n1.id)
```

**EDIT 3 (objects in the same address)**

Try this example:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        print('Created a new A %s with name %s' % (self, name))

def f(name):
    # create a new object A
    a = A(name)
    # a not stored anywhere, so Python will delete it now

f('one')
f('two')
f('three')
```

In my test, it outputs:

```
Created a new A <__main__.A object at 0x00000000029C0CF8> with name one
Created a new A <__main__.A object at 0x00000000029C0CF8> with name two
Created a new A <__main__.A object at 0x00000000029C0CF8> with name three
```

Comment: I just tried that and the it all points to the same object in memory.  As just mentioned above, I thought that that the state of where the yeild statement was as it went along, was held in the obj in memory. <generator object gen at 0x7f15eaba64c8>
<generator object gen at 0x7f15eaba64c8>
1
<generator object gen at 0x7f15eaba64c8>
<generator object gen at 0x7f15eaba64c8>
1

Comment: In my results, from running your suggestion(posted in my comment, are all pointing to the same 'generator object gen' and not the function object.

Comment: Just because two objects are in the same address does not mean they are the same object. You create and object, then you delete it and create another one in the same place...

Answer (score 0):

You created two generators; each call to `Note.gen()` produces a new generator object. The same would happen if you made these functions outside the class.